# Creating a hash from another hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently working with two different hashes that contain common values and I would like to normalize the hash key names.

Hash #1 looks like:

```
files = [{ "filename" => "file.txt","path" => "/folder/file.txt" }]
```

While Hash #2 looks like:

```
files = [{ "file" => "file.txt", "dir" => "/folder/file.txt" }]
```

Is there a way to loop through hash #2 and create a new hash so the keys are "filename" and "path" instead of "file" and "dir"?

Comment: You just want to change the value of the keys. ? Or do you want to have the value as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just replace your key with the new key:

```
files["path"] = files.delete("dir")
```

`delete` returns the value deleted, so you're effectively moving what *was* at `files['dir']` to `files['path']`.

There is no magic method in Ruby to automate this process for your two arrays; you'd have to loop over the first one, find the value in the second one, and perform the above `delete` operation:

```
files1.each do |key,value|
  if old_key = files2.key(value)
    files2[key] = files2.delete(old_key)
  end
end
```

This has the potential to overwrite values if the keys are already taken in the second array. If you're certain that every value in `files1` is also in `files2`, you can skip the if statement and simply use `files2[key] = files2.delete(files2.find(value))` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
files1.concat(files2.map { |old_hash| 
    { 
        "filename" => old_hash["file"], 
        "path" => old_hash["dir"]
    }
})
```